# Adding new column in dataframe counting rows from another dataframe

Tags: r

Have searched on the forums for a solution but couldn't find one.

I have data on companies' financials in one dataframe (df1) and data on acquisitions made in another dataframe (df2). The data is in the same format as below.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c('111111','111111', '222222', '333333', '444444'),
              year=c(2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2011))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c('111111', '111111', '111111', '111111', '333333'),
              year=c(2010,2010,2010,2011,2011))´
```

My goal is to create a new column in df1 with values that count each observation in df2 that matches both the ID and the year of the row in df1. I need a variable that counts the number of acquisitions made by each company each year. Below is the desired output.

```
#output should look like following in df1
# ID      year  count of observations in df2 per year
# 111111  2010  3
# 111111  2011  1
# 222222  2010  0
# 333333  2011  1
# 444444  2011  0
```

I have really tried to come up with a solution but haven't got close enough. Hope that somebody would have a solution for this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best way is to use left_join, you only need to change NA by 0:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c('111111','111111', '222222', '333333', '444444'),
                  year=c(2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2011))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c('111111', '111111', '111111', '111111', '333333'),
                  year=c(2010,2010,2010,2011,2011))

library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% count(ID, year) -> summ_df2

df1 %>% left_join(summ_df2)
#> Joining, by = c("ID", "year")
#> Warning: Column `ID` joining factors with different levels, coercing to
#> character vector
#>       ID year  n
#> 1 111111 2010  3
#> 2 111111 2011  1
#> 3 222222 2010 NA
#> 4 333333 2011  1
#> 5 444444 2011 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

---

**One chain operation**
Added following comment by @Ronak Shah

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c('111111','111111', '222222', '333333', '444444'),
                  year=c(2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2011))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c('111111', '111111', '111111', '111111', '333333'),
                  year=c(2010,2010,2010,2011,2011))

library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
 count(ID, year) %>% 
 right_join(df1) %>% 
 replace_na(list(n = 0))

#> Joining, by = c("ID", "year")
#> Warning: Column `ID` joining factors with different levels, coercing to
#> character vector
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   ID      year     n
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 111111  2010     3
#> 2 111111  2011     1
#> 3 222222  2010     0
#> 4 333333  2011     1
#> 5 444444  2011     0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. However, it seems like this code alone would not add the new column 'n' to data frame df1. Is there a quick solution for this?

Comment: Consider reading left_join and right_join documentation. In the first example, left_join function retains all values in df1 and add column "n" which only exists in df2. In "one chain solution" the trick is to use right_join which retains also df1 and add "n" column. You can't simply add n column to df1 since there are some values which are not present in df1.

Comment: " You can't simply add n column to df1 since there are some values which are not present in df1" <- is there any way to get around this as my goal is to create the column 'n' in df1 with the count of acquisitions made each each year by each ID?

Comment: Actually you are creating a data.frame with same values in df1 and adding a new column "n" which is the same that create a "n" column in df1...

Comment: Please if you think your question has been solved, check it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

A non-tidyverse solution. I understand this seems more complex than the `tidyverse` one, just shared it for variety of options.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c('111111','111111', '222222', '333333', '444444'),
                  year=c(2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2011))

df2 <- data.frame(ID=c('111111', '111111', '111111', '111111', '333333'),
                  year=c(2010,2010,2010,2011,2011))


df1$key <- paste(df1$ID,df1$year,sep = "_")

df2$key <- paste(df2$ID,df2$year,sep = "_")


df1$count_of_year <- unlist(lapply(df1$key,function(x) {sum(df2$key %in% x)}))

df1 <- df1[,c(1,2,4)]

df1
#>       ID year count_of_year
#> 1 111111 2010             3
#> 2 111111 2011             1
#> 3 222222 2010             0
#> 4 333333 2011             1
#> 5 444444 2011             0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>